# Convert page to PDF and display on a different page to the conversion?

Tags: .net, pdf, converters, bubble.io

There are many Page to PDF converters but does anyone know of one which can convert a page and display the final pdf on a different page?

My use case is simple, a user can create an invoice in my app and when they click ‘Preview’ I generate the invoice (on a separate page) and then need to show the pdf back on the page they are currently on.

You may wonder why I don’t simply take the user to the invoice page and do it all there, the reason is because my whole website is a one pager, only 500 pixels wide and the invoice needs to be full width, so I have to use a different full wider page.

I read somewhere that Bubble Page to PDF - New Plugin from Zeroqode can not handle this.

Others, such as SelectPDF plugin or DocSpring or very expensive at $49/month upwards.

Comment: The most economic choice is to build a new page with the layout you want to download in PDF (full width), and print the page using the Microsoft print to PDF or adobe pdf printer

Comment: I don't personally want to print them. I need a solution to incorporate into my mobile app so users get to see a pdf (no printing required).